# NSButtons leave artefacts when used as subviews of a custom toolbar view

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

I'm placing a few buttons in a simple rectangular NSview which acts as a custom toolbar.  On first render the buttons/views come out as expected, but every time a button is pressed (and sometimes with no mouse interaction at all) artefacts start appearing.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

I can eliminate the artefacts by calling a [self.toolbarView setNeedsDisplay:YES] in all the action and focus methods but this seems like a hack, is there any clean way to deal with this?

Comment: Tell how you create buttons and search field

Comment: The buttons are regular NSButtons with the image property set with png images, nothing unusual.  The NSSearchField is stock too.  The problem seems to be with placing them as subviews of an NSView where the drawRect: method draws a gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a beginner's problem.  In the drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
```

I was using the param `dirtyRect` for drawing an outline of my view, assuming it was the view's bounds, where in fact it was only the area around the buttons that became dirty when they were pressed.  The 'artefacts' were actually my outline being drawn in the wrong place.

By correctly using the bounds of the view

```
NSRect drawingRect = [self bounds];
```

the 'artefacts' no longer appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You just try to set focus ring for a buttons to 'none' in IB.

Comment: The focus ring is currently set to None, also setting it to Default does not change the problematic behaviour.